# Remove header from class file

Tags: header-footer, document-classes

I'm a TeX newbie, and I try to edit a [template tex class file](http://paste2.org/F3W3BXA2), but I can't find where the header section is defined. It looks like this:

[image: output]

but I want to remove it completely and edit the header from the `.tex` file. I was able to clear the footnote although.

Can someone inform me if removing it is at least possible, because I spent more time trying to removing it than I would like to admit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks like the output from the `crop` package

Comment: Are you using the `draft` option when loading the class?

Comment: As @ChristianHupfer says, this is probably what's responsible: `\AtBeginDocument{
\RequirePackage[cam,center]{crop}
\paperwidth=8.125in
\paperheight=10.875in
\renewcommand*\CROP@horigin{-.5truein}
\renewcommand*\CROP@vorigin{-.5truein}
}%`. Substituting `\AtBeginDocument{
\paperwidth=8.125in
\paperheight=10.875in
}%` would work. **BUT** the only reason to use this class is to conform with conference/journal submission/publication requirements. If you are submitting/publishing with a conference/journal, you ought NOT change the class. If not, it would be better to use a more flexible class.

Comment: @cfr Wanna answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Well.... I converted my comment, if that counts. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [ChristianHupfer noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283667/remove-header-from-class-file?noredirect=1#comment684046_283667), this is probably what's responsible:

```
\AtBeginDocument{% 
  \RequirePackage[cam,center]{crop}% 
  \paperwidth=8.125in 
  \paperheight=10.875in 
  \renewcommand*\CROP@horigin{-.5truein}% 
  \renewcommand*\CROP@vorigin{-.5truein}% 
}%
```

Substituting

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \paperwidth=8.125in 
  \paperheight=10.875in 
}%
```

would work. **BUT** the **only** reason to use this class is to conform with conference/journal submission/publication requirements. If you are submitting/publishing with a conference/journal, you ought **NOT** change the class. If not, it would be better to use a more flexible class.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `noinfo` in the `crop` options:

```
\RequirePackage[cam,center,noinfo]{crop}
```